# custom jackson serializer not working with gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I'm making a web app using Jackson & Jersey. I've made Response POJOs for the APIs hosted. I've made a custom Jackson serializer for a date field as below.

```
class A{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    @JsonSerialize(using = JacksonSerializers.DateSecondsFromEpochUTCSerializer.class)
    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    public void setLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
    }
}
```

And the Serializer is as below:

```
public class JacksonSerializers {

@Component
public static class DateSecondsFromEpochUTCSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeNumber(localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }

}
```

The above code is working fine when the API is called and the response contains the date in the epoch format.

However, The above serialization is not working when I'm trying to make a JSON of the class using GSON lib. I'm getting the below incorrect output:

```
System.out.print(new Gson().toJson(new A()));
```

gives

```
{"localDateTime":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":1,"day":31},"time":{"hour":12,"minute":55,"second":53,"nano":481000000}}}
```

But I want `1485847871`. Basically, I want to serialize LocalDateTime in epoch time in both flows. I'm trying to do now with GSON but it is not a hardcore requirement. Any elegant solution to achieve both results would do.

Comment: Can't the question basically be boiled down to "how do I serialize a LocalDateTime to epoch format using GSON?"? Why is the Jackson part, which apparently works as intended, even a part of the question?

Comment: Because that is not what I intend to ask. I'm already able to parse LocalDateTime to epoch format in Jersey using Jackson. Now, I'm using the same POJO for some other task and this time I'm serializing the POJO into JSON using GSON and this method is not producing the desired result similar to what Jackson is producing. I wanted a common solution to both problems because both things have to run at the same time.

Comment: ObjectMapper (Jackson) has solved both problems. The latter part had a precondition to it i.e. the earlier serializing using Jackson cannot change but the latter can

Comment: And what if someone answers with a Gson solution?

Comment: Then that would also be a correct answer to this problem. A Question can have multiple solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a unified serializer that you can use for both Jackson and GSON. Something along the lines of this:

```
public class DateSecondsFromEpochUTCSerializer
        extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime>
        implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeNumber(convert(localDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime ldt, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(convert(ldt));
    }

    private long convert(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        return ldt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

Install it in your GSON instance like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new DateSecondsFromEpochUTCSerializer())
    .create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(LocalDateTime.now())); // Epoch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still fine with Gson, and not require Jackson to be introduced since it's a totally different library, you can use a custom Gson type adapter:

```java
final class LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeTypeAdapter = new LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter();

    private LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> getLocalDateTimeTypeAdapter() {
        return localDateTimeTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final LocalDateTime value)
            throws IOException {
        out.value(value.toEpochSecond(UTC));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(in.nextLong()).atZone(UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

This is similar to Gson the `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` pair, but it's more efficient since the latter require JSON trees to be built in memory, whilst type adapters work in streaming fashion and may generate values not accumulating an intermediate state much. Then just configure your `Gson` instance:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, getLocalDateTimeTypeAdapter())
        .create();
final String json = gson.toJson(new A());
out.println(json);
final A a = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
out.println(a.localDateTime);
```

And it would produce something like:

> {"localDateTime":1485871467}
>   2017-01-31T14:04:27

both for serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new A())
```